# Displaying an image in a ListView from a Access database

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I am using ListViews in order to display data from an Access table in visual studio.

I have an image saved in the database as a OLE Object. When I run the website in visual studio  instead of seeing the image the output is

```
System.Byte[]
```

My question is how do you get the image to display instead of this text? The connection is working as all the other data is being shown.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" 
        GroupItemCount="3" onselectedindexchanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server" style="background-color:#FFF8DC;">
                ReqPlate:
                <asp:Label ID="ReqPlateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ReqPlate") %>' />
                <br />CarName:
                <asp:Label ID="CarNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CarName") %>' />
                <br />Miles:
                <asp:Label ID="MilesLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Miles") %>' />
                <br />EngineSize:
                <asp:Label ID="EngineSizeLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("EngineSize") %>' />
                <br />Fuel:
                <asp:Label ID="FuelLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fuel") %>' />
                <br />Description:
                <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                <br />Price:
                <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' />
                <br />Image:
                <asp:Image ID="ImageLabel" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>' />
                <br />
            </td>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Can u post the code - how you're trying to display the image?

Comment: There is no code as I have used the wizard to set it up.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't do. Blob fields require some manipulation (e.g. directly written to output stream and referenced from elsewhere as SRC form IMG tag) before you can use them as images on a Web page

Comment: There must be a way to use ListViews to display images in c#.

Comment: Ok, can you please tell me what this is so I can then begin to code it?

Comment: Google for "Display BLOB as Image" you will find many pointers, for example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13561/How-to-read-BLOBs-and-display-them